# How do I get a button instead of a Submit

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here I am again with another seemingly simple question I just cannot find the answer to.  I would like to use an input type="button" but asp:Button always gives me a type="submit."

```
<asp:Button runat="server" bla bla bla />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
```

I tested it and it renders an `<input type="button" />`

Comment: It is going in a table that is runat server and the compiler whines about non-asp html elements going in that table.

Answer (score 4):

An **asp button** is set up by **default** to post a page back to the server when it is clicked, which is why it is rendered as a submit button.

If you dont want a postback then there is no need to use the **asp:button control**

***Regular* html button should do the job**:

```
 <input type="button" value="My Button"/>
```

you can still format html controls on the server

```
<input ID="MyButton" runat="server" type="button" value="My Button"/>
```

Comment: This was a great answer.  It was not the answer to my question, but it was a better answer to my problem than the answer to my question was.  Thanks for looking past my ignorance to see what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with the button?

You should probably just use an HTML button, not an ASP one.